# Overriding Obj-C-methods in Swift using Swift enums

Tags: objective-c, swift, enums

I have the following Objective-C class which uses an Objective-C enum:

`MyClass.h`:

```
typedef NS_ENUM(NSInteger, MyEnum) {
  MyEnumCase1
};

@interface MyClass : NSObject

-(void)method:(MyEnum)param;

@end
```

`MyClass.m`:

```
@implementation MyClass

-(void)method:(MyEnum)param {}

@end
```

I can subclass `MyClass` in Swift and override the method like this:

`SubClass.swift`

```
class SubClass: MyClass {    
  override func method(_ param: MyEnum) {}
}
```

But if I define the enum in Swift instead of in Objective-C, overriding the method fails:

`MyClass.h`:

```
// Forward declare the enum in Objective-C
typedef NS_ENUM(NSInteger, MyEnum);

@interface MyClass : NSObject

-(void)method:(MyEnum)param;

@end
```

`SubClass.swift`:

```
@objc enum MyEnum: NSInteger {
  case case1
}

class SubClass: MyClass {
  override func method(_ param: MyEnum) {} // Error
}
```

In this case, overriding the method fails with the error

> Method does not override any method from its superclass

The enum itself works in Swift, I can add the following method to SubClass, and it compiles:

```
func useEnum() {
  let x = MyEnum.case1
}
```

Why does the overriding fail?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When I opened the Generated Interface of MyClass.h, Xcode showed something like this:

```
import Foundation

open class MyClass : NSObject {
}
```

Nothing more but comments.

Seems **Swift cannot import incomplete enums**, so methods which use such types are not imported neither.

So, your `@objc enum MyEnum` just declares a new enum type, and `override func method(_ param: MyEnum)` is an attempt to override a method which does not exist in its superclass, from the Swift side.

***The enum itself works in Swift***

Of course. The enum works even if you removed the line of `typedef` (with all lines using it) from MyClass.h .

The enum works even if you specify some different type than `NSInteger`:

```
@objc enum MyEnum: UInt8 {
    case case1
}
```

Seems you cannot write an actual definition of an enum in Swift, which is declared as an incomplete enum in Objective-C.